# What's meta page still reflects Stack Overflow & mSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The [What's meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page seems to not have the updated `$SITE` variable. I thought you fixed this, Shog! Also, some of the wording needs to be changed, as it was more specific to Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]

Can you fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gosh, somebody read the help center?!

Sure, have an update!

Comment: ... you only read it when looking for bugs.